# Facing Problem in drawing counters for resized Image in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, contour

I am facing Problem during drawing counters on the resigned image. Both the Original image and Resigned image have same content only the difference is the size.

Original Image Size: 1275x1650
Resized Image size  : 338 x478

Is I am doing completely wrong from algorithm point of view (Like Thinking the draw counter on Resized image by resizing counters too ?

Below is the code ::

```
img=r"C:\5_cube.tif"
img = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Code to Find edges of Square using Canny edge detection method and finding contours and drawing in Back Line
edges = cv2.Canny(img_gray, 0, 100)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 0, 0), 5)

#Save contours

cv2.imwrite(r"C:\Users\burli\Desktop\1.tif",img)
```

I am successful in drawing counters on original image .
Below code is for resized image

```
image_resize=r"C:\ImageResize.tif"
image_resize = cv2.imread(image_resize, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
height = np.size(image_resize, 0)
width = np.size(image_resize, 1)
ratio = width/height
CounterNewValue = np.multiply(ratio, contours)
#Making Float CounterNewValue to int
for i in CounterNewValue:
     for j in range(len(i)):
         CounterNewValue[j] = CounterNewValue[j].astype(int)

cv2.drawContours(image_resize, CounterNewValue, -1, (0, 0, 0), 5)

cv2.imwrite(r"C:\3.tif",image_resize)
```

Below is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/EffectMainFunction.py", line 17, in <module>
    ObjConturesCreation.ExtractColorFromImage()
  File "C:\conturesCreation.py", line 34, in ExtractColorFromImage
    cv2.drawContours(image_resize, CounterNewValue, -1, (0, 0, 0), 5)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2511: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'cv::drawContours'
```

Please help me over this .

Comment: By "counter" (a device or process for indicating a number or amount), do you actually mean "contour" (an outline especially of a curving or irregular figure)?

Comment: @DanMašek I agree it's the indication of number or amount which have the details of the edges . But when we use draw counter it draws the edges for the values .